# Create tables for default and custom templates in SQL

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I need to create a data model representing projects. Now there are some built-in default projects and there should be the ability to create custom projects also. I have tried to model like below. But I cannot figure out how I can incorporate default and custom projects in this model. Custom projects can have their own extra attributes(not necessary though).

So how can I include the above functionality in this model?
Or is this model enough and new rows in the tables represent each new project(either default or custom)? But then how can I provide the ability to add new attributes for custom projects if required?

Below is the simple relationship that I have created.

[image]

Note: There will only be one config for one project and configs of different projects may have different attributes.

Comment: Can you add a third table, which is a tall object with the project_id and attributes? A project_id can have multiple rows (one per attribute). Or another idea is storing the attributes  as json format in your configs table.

Comment: attributes will be user defined. will it be better if i create multiple tables for each config? like `project_config_table_1`, `project_config_table_2` and so on with each having it attributes and id to `projects` table?

Comment: @Isolated I have added a note on a constraint that I had missed before.

Comment: Multiple tables for each config doesn't seem right, but I'm not a dba, but rather, just a common miner. I defer to the experts, who may want to better understand how these attributes are named and created. For example, if two users want an attribute for Color, but one names it Color and the other names is Colour, then how should this behavior be handled?

Comment: @Isolated That is a nice question. In my case, such scenarios do not arise usually. So it is ok to consider every attribute for an user to be unique. So 1 project will have 1 project config. Each config can have custom attributes. There can be default configs for default projects.